# Is it possible to use dedicated GPU and integrated GPU at the same time? if so how?

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, multiple-monitors

I have an AMD R9 380x and Intel HD 530 and want to run a monitor on both connected via DVI at the same time. I can get output from both GPUs but not at the same time by changing kernel boot parameters.
AMD add parameter "amdgpu.modeset=1"
Intel starts by default
I open terminal and run xrandr | grep connected
while running off of the Intel GPU

```
ryan*******@********:~$ xrandr | grep connected
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1-0 disconnected
HDMI-1-0 disconnected
DVI-1-0 connected
```

the DVI-1-0 shows disconnected when i unplug the DVI cable from the AMD GPU but there is no output to the monitor.
running lsmod only shows the Intel i915 loaded.
using command "sudo modprobe amdgpu" causes lightdm to restart.
lsmod now shows i915 and amdgpu.
still nothing displayed on AMD monitor.
When i try to open displays in system settings it crashes.
xrandr shows the same output as before.
This setup works in windows and Mac OS X so it isn't my hardware.
is there something I am missing?
EDIT:
I am running Kernel 4.5 rc3
using Intel's drivers and open source AMD drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work by installing the xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu package